# Why is Newtonsoft converting a missing integer field to its default value in F#?

Tags: json, f#, json.net, json-deserialization

When using Newtonsoft for deserializing a JSON object in F#, I noticed that the deserialization process converts the missing integer fields to its default values. In the following example, the missing integer field in `instanceB` is converted to an integer field with default value (`0`). But when the missing field is `Name` in `instanceC` (which is of type `string`), it converts to `null`. Why is the output of deserialization different based on the type of the fields?

```
#r """Newtonsoft.Json.dll"""

open Newtonsoft.Json

type Test = {
    Id:   int
    Name: string
}

let instanceA = """{"Id": 1, "Name": "A"}"""
let instanceB = """{"Name": "A"}"""
let instanceC = """{"Id": 1}"""

let A = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(instanceA)
let B = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(instanceB)
let C = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(instanceC)

printfn "%A" A
printfn "%A" B
printfn "%A" C
```

Output:

```
val A : Test = { Id = 1
                 Name = "A" }
val B : Test = { Id = 0
                 Name = "A" }
val C : Test = { Id = 1
                 Name = null }
```

Comment: If I were a beginner on .NET and with F#, it is quite possible I would have expected an empty string rather than null. That strings can even be null is illogical, and a well known flaw in the design of .NET. (There was another comment here that was deleted, so this comment of mine is now slightly out of context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET some types have `null` as a possible value and some don't. The latter are called "value types", and the former are called "reference types".

`int` is a value type, so it can't be `null`.

`string` is a reference type, so it can.

Every type does have a default value though. For reference types the default value is `null`. For value types it depends on the type, but usually it's some variation of zero. So those are the values you're getting.